# How to resize std::vector with unique objects

Tags: c++, resize, stdvector

I have a vector of objects. Each object has a `boost::shared_ptr` to a noncopyable object (a `boost::signal`). the object's default constructor creates the boost::signal object.

```
struct FuncRef
{
    typedef boost::signal0<void, > Func;
    boost::shared_ptr <Func> function;
    FuncRef():
        function(new Func)
    {
    }
};
```

To set my vector to contain X individual objects, I did this:-

```
vec.resize(X);
```

This didn't do what I expected, because it uses the default constructor to make one object, and then the copy constructor to make the duplicates. I end up with X objects, but they all point to the same `boost::signal0` object.

Is there an easier way of building my vector correctly than just using `push_back` in a `for` loop?

Comment: You could make your class inherit `boost::noncopyable` to detect such errors at compile-time.

Comment: @Bjorn - the class has to be copyable, as it's in a vector. That's why I have to use a shared_ptr. The problem is that it's using copying when I wasn't expecting it to...

Comment: Correct, what was I thinking?

Comment: If you have C++0x, you might want `while (vec.size() < X) vec.emplace_back();`. That expresses the fact that you don't want any copying, but sadly there's no `emplace_several_times`. Better, it should allow you to use a `unique_ptr` instead of a `shared_ptr`, so your elements are movable but not copyable. That allows you to actually ban the copying that you don't want. Then again, it may be that under C++0x, `boost::signal` is movable itself, I don't know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only way I can think of is to use `reserve` to make the vector allocate the memory you need (as @Jonathan answered). You can the use `generate_n` with an `std::back_inserter` to add the elements:

```
FuncRef makeFuncRef() {
    return FuncRef();
}

vec.reserve(vec.size() + n);
std::generate(std::back_inserter(vec), n, makeFuncRef);
```

The `reserve` is not necessary with this approach, although it is probably faster if `n` is large.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way I can think of is to reserve the memory beforehand so that only one allocation is needed by the `vector`:

```
vec.reserve(X);
```

Then loop and `push_back()`. Is that not sufficient for your needs?

Comment: Yes, that works, but I was wondering if there was a simple one-liner I was missing...

Comment: Björn has the right idea with `std::generate()` I think. It's not clear what you want to initialize the vector's elements *to*. They have to hold some value (or be undefined.)

Comment: initialised to default constructed objects, using the FuncRef constructor shwon in the code. Bjorn's code will work as-is, but for loops have better readability IMO. Roll on lambdas...

Comment: Lambdas are also tasty but you didn't indicate you could use C++0x features. :)

Answer (score 0):

Are you not able to implement a copy constructor/copy assignment with actual copy semantics? Unless you're having serious performance with the vector filling this seems like the most obvious solution.